# Using Amazon MQ topics as an event source for Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-mq

Is it possible to use amazon mq topics as event sources on AWS Lambda, when I try to add a trigger from the interface and I click amazon mq it automatically assumes I want a queue, if its not possible to do it directly is there any alternative to somehow redirecting messages to aws lambda ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-mq.html) [emphasis mine]:

> Event destinations – Only queue destinations are supported. **However,
> you can use a virtual topic, which behaves as a topic internally while
> interacting with Lambda as a queue**. For more information, see Virtual
> Destinations on the Apache ActiveMQ website, and Virtual Hosts on the
> RabbitMQ website.